# How to use two variables with same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have `url` variable in my iOS project, and I would like it point to `http://localhost:3000/api` when I build the project in DEBUG mode, but when I build the project for RELEASE, I would like the `url` variable to point to `http://example.com/api`

So for I have sketched out the following,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // want to use this variable on DEBUG build
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/"];
#endif
    // want to use this variable on RELEASE build
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/"];
```

but Xcode is complaining that I already declared a `url` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // want to use this variable on DEBUG build
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/"];
#else
    // want to use this variable on RELEASE build
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/"];
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You should define variable before set value
Try this code:

```
NSURL *url;
#ifdef DEBUG
// want to use this variable on DEBUG build
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/"];
#else
// want to use this variable on RELEASE build
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/"];
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not do:

```
NSURL *url;
#ifdef DEBUG
// want to use this variable on DEBUG build
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/"];
#endif
// want to use this variable on RELEASE build
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *did* declare it. Think about it: This is conditional code. So what will the code *actually* look like if `DEBUG` is defined? It will look like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/api/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api/"];
```

Well, that's illegal.